# Why does mercurial's "hg rebase" command take so much time for a relatively large repository?

Tags: version-control, mercurial, rebase

Even though the changeset itself is very small, when I do a "hg rebase" for a relatively large repository (say around 10GB) why does it so much time. What exactly goes on behind the scenes?

Comment: show used rebase syntax (and maybe glog), size of changeset is not relevant here at all, but `-b ` and long diverged history **can be**

Comment: I was just trying something like "hg rebase --rev xxx" without any "-b" option and it takes almost like a minute.

Answer (score 0):

Two quotes from `hg help rebase`

> If you specify neither "-s" nor "-b", rebase uses the parent of the working directory as the base.

+

> If you specify base ("-b/--base"), rebase will select ancestors of base back to but not including the common ancestor with dest.

With used by you syntax and possibly DAG of repo selecting ancestors may be time-consuming task